# What is this device/object that the SpaceX astronauts are holding?

Tags: spacex, astronauts, identify-this-object

Watching [the SpaceX Demo-2 launch preparation livestream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjb9FdVdX5I), I saw both Bob and Doug using some sort of little gadget. It looks like a chunky cell phone, or a flat gopro. It appears to have an LCD on the back side (the side we can see).

[image: identify object 1]
[image: identify object 2]

pictures and learnings from the Saturday launch- he removes it from his leg pouch and sticks it above the monitor. I assume it is velcroed on.

[image: identify object saturday 1]
[image: identify object saturday 2]

Comment: This question was posted only a few seconds before a [similar question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44342/26446).  If one of them receives an answer, the other should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Can we get a timestamp?

Comment: @dragongeek here's the timestamp: [1:53:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjb9FdVdX5I#t=1h53m25s).

Comment: Guesses:
- Accurate clocks, synchronized in-person with the ground equipment. You can't have enough clocks in space travel; accurate timing determines whether you can execute precise maneuvers at all.
- Wireless receiver for telemetry or radio communication from the suits
- Matching retro iPods

Comment: This looks like what was called in shuttle an "egg timer". Just a cheap LCD timer with Velcro on the back. Will seek confirmation.

Comment: yeah, @OrganicMarble, you and CourageousPotato have the leading theory. Especially since I saw him 'stick' it up there, which is what you'd do with a timer.

Comment: Picture of the shuttle eggtimer here https://i.imgur.com/nmiPqK4.jpg (red arrow)

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/63746/6944

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure of his source, but Scott Manley seems to assume these are portable timers. Timestamp of 5:00 at this [Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/MjNlU29c5LY#t=5m).

Comment: That's great! Accepting based on DJSnM's knowledge, if anyone comes along with a more solid source I'll unaccept and move it to theirs.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's [CDN PT2](https://cdnmeasurement.com/product/pt2-4-event-timer-clock-2/) kitchen timer. In shuttle era PT1A was used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It sure looks just like it and CDN is a brand that NASA has used in the past. In fact here is a CDN timer on a [Soyuz](https://youtu.be/fr_hXLDLc38?si=vPLcXlUmC0wmKyc1&t=54). NASA has used other brands also, here is a shot from [STS-132](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/457240main_s132e009359_full.jpg) showing two timers, the brand on the right is Time Check, the brand on the left is different but unfortunately illegible because of a sticker placed over it. Here's John Glenn's Time Check from [STS-95](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/timer-stopwatch-sts-95/nasm_A19990150000)