# Small display manipulation unit in SpaceX Crew Dragon

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2

In the historical SpaceX Demo-2 mission there's a moment when Douglas G. Hurley takes out from the souti's leg bag a small gadget and immediately drops it:

[image]

SpaceX support staff helps and puts the gadget back in Doug's hands. Then he proceeds with something that appears to be remote manipulation of the overhead displays.

What is that small gadget? And, why is it so weirdly unreliable — one unlucky fumbling with the gloved hand, and it is somewhere on the ground, and there's no way the astronaut can pick it up, as they are well connected to their chairs. Even a simple strap would have helped.

Comment: [I was wondering too](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/what-is-this-device-object-that-the-spacex-astronauts-are-holding) - looks like we posted at the same time.

Comment: This question was posted only a few seconds after a [similar question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44341/26446). If one of them receives an answer, the other should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The other question now has an answer and double the viewcount. Close vote for this question started.