# What is this small white device with LCD and 10 keys on the International Space Station?

Tags: iss

I see this device in many places in International Space Station; what is it called and what does it do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are kitchen timers. See https://www.watchuseek.com/threads/small-white-timing-clock-inside-the-iss.125971/ for example.

Comment: Thanx A lot, it is indeed a programmable timers from pyrex you could add this as an Answer if you wish

Comment: @GdD - no, one increments hours/minutes/second with the top three buttons, selects which of 4 separate concurrent timers with the middle four, and then the bottom 3 are stop/start, clear, and enter. Plus a slide selector on the side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A clear close up of one is at https://www.watchuseek.com/threads/small-white-timing-clock-inside-the-iss.125971/ - they are Pyrex Professional brand kitchen timers.

If the link above does not work, I've found this:

[image]

One can see the 10 buttons. It does seem that NASA did not get ones prominently marked "Pyrex Professional".

You might be amazed how many kitchen timers can be found in labs around the world.

Comment: The venerable kitchen timer, NASA could spend a million and not get something better. I looked at tons of pilots watches for timing turns and patterns in instrument flying and ended up putting a kitchen timer in the cockpit instead.

Comment: Being able to put the timer where you can easily see it, versus having to look down at a wrist on a hand that is trying to do something else, really makes a difference.

Comment: Known to all in ops as "egg timers". Ubiquitous in shuttle as well https://i.imgur.com/QPBSBLm.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble - they seem to be standardized? Would make sense so that you don't have to fumble with each different one on the planet (or off the planet).

Comment: All the ones I remember seeing are exactly what you called out in your answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Given how quickly the styles change at my local cooking store, it seems likely somebody bought a big box full at some point. Nice.

Comment: They didn't have the big red Pyrex logo IIRC, but all the buttons etc...exactly like that one at your link.

Comment: Now I'm picturing a special procurement of space-rated, rad-hard kitchen timers...

Comment: @JonCuster so...mechanical kitchen timers?

Comment: @user3528438 - are you trying to drive the astronauts mad from all the ticking?

Comment: I was hoping it's something more technical like a token generator or such, never expected a kitchen gadget :)

Comment: That link in that watchuseek link returns Access Denied.

Comment: This [lab supplier](https://www.newcomersupply.com/products/lab-essentials-equipment/laboratory-essentials/timers/#n4126) offers them without the Pyrex logo, for $30.

Comment: You can get cheaper timers on Amazon, but ISS is outside the Prime delivery area :-(

Comment: Well, certainly same day… Blue Origin is working on it.

Answer (score 3):

The Smithsonian Air and Space Museum [has one that was used on STS-95](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/timer-stopwatch-sts-95/nasm_A19990150000) on display.  The description states it was used by John Glenn on STS-95 in 1998, and the country of origin is "United States".  So it's possible these were custom designed for the space program and either also sold on the civilian market, or copied.  The first photo below is the actual timer used by John Glenn, and the second states it is a "replica" of the ISS version.  The "Time Check" trademark logo would indicate that it was made by an outside entity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So time check was the exact logo found on the ones on ISS, I zoomed in and I see it now, thanx @Greg Miller